# limit the UILabel to 500 character and than Truncate the UIlabel in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uilabel

I want to display first 500 character in UILabel and than display Truncate icon if there is more than 500 character available.But i dont know how can i limit 500 character to truncate the text?.

Here is my code

```
label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 350, self.bounds.size.width, 30)];
   // In this case value of self.bounds.size.width is "427"

    label2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label2.numberOfLines = 2;
    label2.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    label2.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
    [self addSubview:label2]

         //Here is Implimentation code of my label

 NSString *temp = [galleryEntryTree objectForKey:@"description"];// calling lebel text from database
coverView.label2.text = temp;
coverView.label2.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
coverView.label2.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
```

Just tell me guys how can i display min 500 character and than truncate it( if longer than 500)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: coverView.label2.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap; and adjust your height or else dynamically increase the height.

Comment: You can try using a NSMutableString and truncate the text before setting the label.text

Comment: yourLabel.text.length use this in if and then use stringbyappendingstring or stringwithformat

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just truncate the string if it's longer than 500 characters. Only caveat: make sure to not break it in the middle of a [surrogate pair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Code_points_U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF):

```
NSString *temp = [galleryEntryTree objectForKey:@"description"];
if ([temp length] > 500) {
    NSRange range = [temp rangeOfComposedCharacterSequencesForRange:(NSRange){0, 500}];
    temp = [temp substringWithRange:range];
    temp = [temp stringByAppendingString:@" …"];
}
coverView.label2.text = temp;
```

Answer (score 4):

To display only 500 character just use below code:

```
NSString *string = YOUR_TEXT;
if ([string length] >500) {
    string = [string substringToIndex:500];
}
```

Hope this will help you.

All the best !!!

Comment: Never split strings without making sure not to break surrogate pairs.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to do it in Swift 2.2:

```
let maxLength = 500
if originalString.characters.count > maxLength {
   let range = originalString.rangeOfComposedCharacterSequencesForRange(Range<String.Index>(originalString.startIndex ..< originalString.startIndex.advancedBy(maxLength)))
   let tmpValue = originalString.substringWithRange(range).stringByAppendingString(" …")
   // use tmpValue
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one it'l helps you.

```
label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 350, self.bounds.size.width, 30)];
   // In this case value of self.bounds.size.width is "427"
 label2.text=@"your text................................";
 if([label2.text length]>500)
        label2.text=[label2.text substringToIndex:500];


    label2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label2.numberOfLines = 2;
    label2.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    label2.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
    [self addSubview:label2]
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be simply done by

```
NSString *LabelNewText = [YourLabelName.text substringToIndex:500];
```

Here 500 or less than 500 characters will be displayed and all the characters exceeding that will be truncated.

NSString *string = LabelNewText.text;

```
if ([string length] >500)
{
   string = [string substringToIndex:500];                                       
}
```

Comment: This crashes if the length of text is below 500.

Comment: You can check the length of string by                           NSString *string = LabelNewText.text;
if ([string length] >500) {
    string = [string substringToIndex:500];                                       
}

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.0 version**

```
let maxLength = 300 //char length
if originalString.characters.count > maxLength {
            let range =  originalString.rangeOfComposedCharacterSequences(for: originalString.startIndex..<originalString.index(originalString.startIndex, offsetBy: maxLength))
            let tmpValue = originalString.substring(with: range).appending("...")
        }
```